# Can I add an android custom title bar and action bar at the same time just after the other

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-titlebar

In My application I need to add two tools bars.First one has application name and two other buttons. Next one for tabs. I created it using action bar. In portrait view it works fine. But in landscape view it appears as a one toolbar. Those tabs display as a spinner navigation in the first bar. But I need to display it as another bar just after the first one (appear same as in portrait view.)
Because of this issue I tried to create custom toolbar as the first one. But now I'm getting exception as:

```
01-30 11:05:59.385: E/AndroidRuntime(2712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 11:05:59.385: E/AndroidRuntime(2712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtest/com.example.androidtest.HomeActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

This is the code I used in Activity:

```
private ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

window_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Custom Window Text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/titlebutton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What should I do to fix this issue or else any other way to make two toolbars just after the other in both portrait and landscape views ?

Comment: it sounds like you might need to create a separate view for your activity in landscape mode. can you share some of your code?

Comment: @sirFunkenstine I already create separate view for activity. But The tool bar is not managing by them. I don't have much experience in android. But I believe there should be a way to manage toolbar to solve my issue. I read about splitting action bar but I found only about bottom bar though we can create top bar according to the documentation.